# language server onCompletion is only listening to letters [a-z], how do I enable a period (.)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

The lsp-sample in repository https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/lsp-sample shows how to implement `onCompletion`

the server only listens to letters [a-z] and not to a period (.)
I have seen that this is controlled with `triggerCharacters`, but it is not clear to me where to set these.
It seems logical that this needs to be done in the client part, but it seems I can only register another `onCompletion` handler.
Can anybody shed some light?

This is the server side code:

```ts
// This handler provides the initial list of the completion items.
connection.onCompletion(
    (_textDocumentPosition: TextDocumentPositionParams): CompletionItem[] => {
        // The pass parameter contains the position of the text document in
        // which code complete got requested. For the example we ignore this
        // info and always provide the same completion items.
        return [
            {
                label: 'TypeScript',
                kind: CompletionItemKind.Text,
                data: 1
            },
            {
                label: 'JavaScript',
                kind: CompletionItemKind.Text,
                data: 2
            }
        ];
    }
);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trigger characters are specified in the `ServerCapabilities` of the [`Initialize`](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/specification-current/#initialize) response:

```ts
connection.onInitialize((params: InitializeParams) => {
    // ...
    return {
        capabilities: {
            // ...
            completionProvider: {
                triggerCharacters: ["."]
            }
        }
    };
});
```

See also: `CompletionOptions` of the [Completion Request](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/specification-current/#textDocument_completion).